# Test for true random number generator

Tags: stream-cipher

For my networks project I have decided to implement a youtube-based secret key generator used in creating a self-synchronizing stream cipher hash function. Basically all the youtube video comments corresponding to a pseudo-random number being input to the search bar will be stored in a csv file, a file descriptor moved to pseudo-random part of the file and a combination of the ascii values of random keystrokes from that part and some pseudorandom numbers will generate the secret key. My question is, when using a pseudo-random generator to select random parts of a truly random source, is the result truly random or pseudo-random? I'm sorry I'm totally a newbie. (Operating under the assumption that youtube comments are supposedly random). Also, is there any way to prove that something is truly random?

Comment: Hiya!  Could you please expand on the role of the pseudo-random generator. Why is a PRNG selecting from a TRNG?

Answer (score 3):

> When using a pseudo-random generator to select random parts of a truly random source, is the result truly random or pseudo-random?

The result could well be distinguishable from random, for one or both of two causes:

- it could be that some of the selected random parts are selected twice, which could be distinguishable;
- the (unspecified) pseudo-random generator could receive input from the truly random source that makes its selections biased in some way.

---

On the other hand, *any* method of selection of parts of a truly random source is guaranteed to produce true random if it selects parts in the source's output based on their position only (not on their content), and never selects any part twice.

---

Beside an educative value, I can't discern any practical application to what the question envisions.